# In-app payment Google Play - app crashing after buying item

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, google-play

I'm trying to implement 'in-app payment' in my app.

I've modified example `TrivialDrive` app and everything worked perfectly fine. Now I'm trying to sell multiple items and it's not working as I expected. I've modified the code a bit, but apparently I'm doing something completely wrong.

The 1st purchase is perfectly fine. Then after the 2nd charges money, the app crashes. On the third purchase it charges money, but it doesn't add items in game. It's just behaving weirdly...

I've done some changes in the original app:

I've created multiple items, put the in ArrayList:

```
static final String GOLD_3 = "gold_3";
static final String GOLD_5 = "gold_5";
//and so on
static final ArrayList<String> goods = new ArrayList<String>();


@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.buy_screen_layout);

    goods.add(GOLD_3);
    goods.add(GOLD_5);
    //and so on
```

I've created multiple buttons, for different items and created `onClickListeners` for them:

```
         @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Buy gas button clicked.");
            setWaitScreen(true);
            Log.d(TAG, "Launching purchase flow for gas.");
            String payload = "";
            mHelper.launchPurchaseFlow(BuyScreen.this, GOLD_3, RC_REQUEST, mPurchaseFinishedListener, payload);

        }
```

It only varies on different items.. `gold_5`, `gold_10` etc.

I slightly changed `QueryInvertoryFinishedListener`, where I control in cycle whether is all bought items consumed:

```
    IabHelper.QueryInventoryFinishedListener mGotInventoryListener = new IabHelper.QueryInventoryFinishedListener() {

    public void onQueryInventoryFinished(IabResult result, Inventory inventory) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Query inventory finished.");
        if (mHelper == null)
            return;

        if (result.isFailure()) {
            complain("Failed to query inventory: " + result);
            return;
        }

        Log.d(TAG, "Query inventory was successful.");

        for (String good : goods) {
            Purchase goldPurchase = inventory.getPurchase(good);
            if (goldPurchase != null && verifyDeveloperPayload(goldPurchase)) {
                Log.d(TAG, "We have gold. Consuming it.");
                mHelper.consumeAsync(inventory.getPurchase(good), mConsumeFinishedListener);
                return;
            }

        }

        updateUi();
        setWaitScreen(false);
        Log.d(TAG, "Initial inventory query finished; enabling main UI.");
    }
};
```

Again added cycle in `OnIabPurchaseFinishedListener`:

```
    IabHelper.OnIabPurchaseFinishedListener mPurchaseFinishedListener = new IabHelper.OnIabPurchaseFinishedListener() {
    public void onIabPurchaseFinished(IabResult result, Purchase purchase) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Purchase finished: " + result + ", purchase: " + purchase);

        if (mHelper == null)
            return;

        if (result.isFailure()) {
            complain("Error purchasing: " + result);
            setWaitScreen(false);
            return;
        }

        if (!verifyDeveloperPayload(purchase)) {
            complain("Error purchasing. Authenticity verification failed.");
            setWaitScreen(false);
            return;
        }

        Log.d(TAG, "Purchase successful.");

        for (String good : goods) {
            if (purchase.getSku().equals(good)) {
                Log.d(TAG, "Purchase is gas. Starting gas consumption.");
                mHelper.consumeAsync(purchase, mConsumeFinishedListener);
            }
        }



    }
};
```

And again added cycle and regocnizion of type of item which is user buying:

```
IabHelper.OnConsumeFinishedListener mConsumeFinishedListener = new IabHelper.OnConsumeFinishedListener() {
    public void onConsumeFinished(Purchase purchase, IabResult result) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Consumption finished. Purchase: " + purchase + ", result: " + result);

        // if we were disposed of in the meantime, quit.
        if (mHelper == null)
            return;

        if (result.isSuccess()) {

            Log.d(TAG, "Consumption successful. Provisioning.");

            String numberOfGold = purchase.getSku();

            if (numberOfGold.equals("gold_3")) {
                GameData.totalGoldCoins = +3;
            } else if (numberOfGold.equals("gold_5")) {
                GameData.totalGoldCoins = +5;
            } else if (numberOfGold.equals("gold_10")) {
                GameData.totalGoldCoins = +10;
            } else if (numberOfGold.equals("gold_15")) {
                GameData.totalGoldCoins = +15;
            } else if (numberOfGold.equals("gold_20")) {
                GameData.totalGoldCoins = +20;
            }

            saveData();


        } else {
            complain("Error while consuming: " + result);
        }
        updateUi();
        setWaitScreen(false);
        Log.d(TAG, "End consumption flow.");
    }
};
```

...in `saveData()` I use `sharedPreferences`. All gold coins are stored through game in special class in static variable.

I have a hunch, that I'm doing something wrong with those cycles (trying to consume consumed product or something other non-sense).

Any ideas, what exactly am I doing wrong? Can I somehow turn on logCat on this published (alpha) appliaction? Or any way, how to test is faster (on real transaction) then in few hours after it will be finally published/updated?

Thanks for any ideas!

Comment: Problem solved. It was enough to call `mHelper.consumeAsync(purchase, mConsumeFinishedListener)` without going through cycle.